# Optimize data model Firestore

Tags: firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have an app to learn idioms with songs. I'm using Firestore as my database.

Actual data Structure:

- Users

  - (USER DATA)
- Songs

  - (SONG DATA)
  - Lyric (Array of phrases [phrase:’’, startTime: …])
- Plays (Store data of each time that users play a song)

  - Score
  - SongID

I want to add the functionality of each user can know what words learned while playing as a kind of vocabulary.

```
- Users
    -Vocabulary
       -Word1
         -wordId
         -timesPlayed
         -lastTimeAt(unix)
         -translation
- Words
    -Word
      -translation
      (more word data)
```

I thought that each time a song is added, a Firebase function will be triggered that will separate all the words in the song and verify if the word exists in the general vocabulary of the application and if it is not added.
Each time a user plays a song the words of this is added to their own language (only of the songs that have been played) and if it already exists, there are the number of times that it was practiced as well as the date of the last practice.

The vocabulary of the users only keep references to palbras in the general vocabulary since they can edit it collaboratively to all users.

The problem I have is that many scriptures are made in Firestore around 300 words for each user who plays a song, compared to what I currently do without this functionality (2 writings) are demadas there is a way to optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize the number of writings into Firestore.

What I would do is have three different objects:

1. timesPlayed
2. lastTimeAt(unix)
3. translation

Each object would then have the id of the word as a key. Objects two and three represent no issue, however, the timesPlayed object would get quiet expensive on the client side or the cloud function that will run it. (I would do it in the client).

You could nest the three objects inside a Vocabulary one and use the option of merging set to true when updating your user document.

Hope it helps.